# Python Import From Folder Above Without Using Path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For Python 3, in this sandbox, foo has a function print_bar() I want to use in script1.

```
myApp/
      main_folder/                         
                 helper/                 
                       __init__.py
                       foo.py
                 scripts/                  
                       script1.py
```

In script1:

```
from ..helpers import foo

foo.print_bar()
```

I am met with "ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package".

Fine I'll try the sys path stuff thing I see on the other SO questions.

```
import os
import sys

# Add parent folder path to sys.path
cur_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent_path = os.path.dirname(cur_path)
sys.path.append(parent_path)

from helpers import foo

foo.print_bar()
```

Okay this works but is a bit convoluted. Is there not a simpler way to say, "Go up a directory and the import x?"

Seems like relative import along the lines of "from ..helpers import foo" is what should work but am I not getting it right or am I not using it for its intended purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following methods can be used to include parent folder in python path:

```
import sys, os

sys.path.append('..')                  # method 1

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..')) # method 2

sys.path.append(os.pardir)             # method 3
```